# reading and updating a large xml file in java

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have an XML file about 400 MB 
I need to find a specific element and then reformat its date attribute from mm-dd-yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy
Here is the code that I am using

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputXML);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
//format the date 
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("empDetails");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
    String oldDate =nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("doj").getNodeValue();
    String newValue = //formatted to dd-mm-yyyy 
nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("doj").setTextContent(newValue);
}

    //now write back to file 
    // write the content into xml file
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer;        
transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();      
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(fileName));     
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

However this is throwing out of memory 
On windows 32 bit - it fails

So I tried this on a unix box and set the memory to :
**java -Xmx3072m -classpath . MyTest**

It did run for some time but failed again

Question - is it possible to be handling a file of 400 MB  where I want to selectivey update and save? ( am sure the answer is yes )
Is my code bad - anything that I should change ? ( no unix shell scripts as an alternate solution please - my intent is to use java ) 
should I be bumping up the heap size further ?
Thanks,
satish

Comment: Instead of using DOM parser (i.e. building entire XML in memory), use SAX parser.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be better to use the StAX api read the document like a stream while writing out (again using StAX) the parts you don't want to change immediately to a a temporary file. When you get to a part you are interested in, change the values before feeding it back to the temporary file. When you are done you can rename the temporary file over the old one.

I'd recommend the [`XMLEventReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) and [`XMLEventWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.html). `XMLEvents` you don't care about you can pass directly through from reader to writer. This will only keep small parts of the document you are working on in memory.

```
XMLEventReader reader = ...;
XMLEventWriter writer = ...;
XMLEvent cursor;

while(reader.hasNext()){
  cursor = reader.nextEvent();
  if(doICareAboutThisEvent(cursor)){
      writer.add(changeEvent(cursor));
  }else{
      writer.add(cursor);
  }

}
```

Obviously the implementation can be more complicated and your decisions about which elements to care about and edit can be more complicated than the state of a single element. This is just a very simple example.